# Bounding improper integrals from above

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by a system of finitely many polynomial inequalities with integer coefficients. Assume that $S$ is not bounded, but $S$ has finite volume $v$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can anyone describe an algorithm for generating a sequence of rational numbers that converges to $v$ from above?

Comment: I take it that you are given the inequalities, but you aren't given $v$?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Exactly. I don't see how to systematically approximate $v$ from above given an arbitrary set of inequalities for which $v$ is finite.